# How to use your pointer as a writing pen in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I want to find a way to make possible to draw on the entire browser page or a part of it using the mouse pointer. It will be just a blue line that it will be created when the button is clicked.

Is there any technology instead of Flash?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. It was the first result on Google when searching for JavaScript Painting. It's a step-by-step guide on how to use the JavaScript canvas to create a drawing tool.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Comment: This is great example. Thank you! Please tell me, how can I erase the canvas using a button ?